# Loading JSON into a Highcharts pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, getjson

I think what I probably have is a simple problem. This works great ..

`$(document).ready(function() {
// Original data
var data = [{
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "y": 3.0
}, {
    "name": "NewYork",
    "y": 2.0
}, {
    "name": "Berlin",
    "y": 3.5
}, {
    "name": "London",
    "y": 1.5
}];
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
});`

I wanted to modify the code to load using getJSON and the JSON is formatted correctly.
So I did this...

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("etstats?rtype=bestpgs_ec&month=2016-06-01&no_requested=10", function(json){
    var data = json
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
  });
 });
});`

I checked the JSON in Firebug and it's formatted correctly using "name" and "y"

`[{"name": "14704", "y": "0.17"}, {"name": "14706", "y": "0.20"}, {"name": "21304", "y": "0.25"}, {"name"
: "23201", "y": "0.39"}, {"name": "23501", "y": "0.42"}, {"name": "17102", "y": "0.46"}, {"name": "15001"
, "y": "0.48"}, {"name": "23002", "y": "0.50"}, {"name": "13201", "y": "0.50"}, {"name": "17401", "y"
: "0.52"}]`

Does anyone have any pointers as to why my chart won't render?

**Note: Edited to add answer. The quoted values were the issue. They are removed by iterating over them and eval the value.**

`$.getJSON("etstats?rtype=bestpgs_ec&month=2016-06-01&no_requested=10", function(json){
    data = json
    $.each(data, function (i, point) {
         point.y = eval(point.y);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({`

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but your `"y"` values have double quotes in your second version and do not in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the data given above. I think highchart just doesn't accept `string` type in `y`

here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/fohoqasugo/edit?html,js,output)

a valid JSON format should be

```
[
  {"name":"14704","y":0.17},
  {"name":"14706","y":0.2},
  {"name":"21304","y":0.25},
  {"name":"23201","y":0.39},
  {"name":"23501","y":0.42},
  {"name":"17102","y":0.46},
  {"name":"15001","y":0.48},
  {"name":"23002","y":0.5},
  {"name":"13201","y":0.5},
  {"name":"17401","y":0.52}
]
```

after your `getJSON` complete, remember doing `JSON.parse` first to get the correct object and then you can finally pass it into highchart

Comment: hiEven: That was it! I modified the answer above to eval the value and remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check that your response of `getJSON` is json string ? If yes, you should do this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to update data on a Pie chart from MySQL using jQuery

First, in PHP: create an array of arrays with value/name pairs and make sure you return "json_encode"d data:

```
   ... [code] ...
   while($aRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oRes)){
      $aData[] = array("y" => $aRow['number'], "name" => $aRow['string']);
   }
   exit(json_encode($aData));
```

Second, create the chart:

```
    oGraph = new Highcharts.chart({
       chart: {
          renderTo: 'graphid',
       ... [code] ...
       plotOptions: {
          pie: {
       ... [code] ...
       series: [{
          name: 'MyName',
          data: []
       ... [code] ...
   });
```

Third, build jQuery code to retrieve data:

```
   $.ajax({
      type     : 'post',
      url      : '/path/to/the/above/php/data-script.php',
      dataType : 'json'
   }).done(function( oJson ) {
      var oObj = [];
      $.each(oJson, function(ix,sliceData) {
         oObj.push({
            name: sliceData.name,
            y: eval(sliceData.y)
         });
      });
      oGraph.series[0].setData(oObj, true);
   });
```

It took me all day to realise that I had to (1) re-package the data and (2) use **eval()** for the value parameter y!!!